# Where to get Windows 7 RTM download?

Tags: windows-7, download, rtm

I hear people are using Windows 7 even before its released and liking it. Any ideas where I can get my copy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The RTM version is only being distributed to OEMs and MSDN or TechNet subscribers. Windows 7 will be released in 3 days. On the 22th, this Thursday.

Answer (score 4):

Windows 7 RTM available to Microsoft partners via [MSDN Library subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/default.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

MSDN and Technet subscribers were given early access to Windows 7 downloads, and developers who attended certain Microsoft conferences were given copies of Windows 7 Ultimate.

Edit: Also, if you recently purchased a computer from a company like Dell or HP, it's possible you qualify for a free or cheap OEM upgrade. I applied for the upgrade on a new HP laptop - it was simple and painless (just had to upload a copy of the receipt) and HP will be mailing me the disc once it's released.

Answer (score 0):

On October 22, Windows 7 will be widely available and you can buy it directly from Microsoft.

The cheapest option at the moment seems to buy the upgrade directly from [Microsoft Store](http://store.microsoft.com/microsoft/Windows-7/category/102?WT.mc_id=winonline_win7promo), where it's billed as a promotion.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone can download the [Windows 7 Enterprise 90-day Trial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx) which is the final release version of the product.

Microsoft do disclaim:

> "We do not recommend that you install this if you are a not an IT Professional or not professionally managing corporate networks"

(but who worrys about disclaimers :¬)

Comment: I tried this one but I prefer Win 7 Ultimate RTM.Because Enterprise Version have some negative options.

Comment: The trial is not upgradable to a working copy after the expire-date, beware of that!